# returning a Promise from an async function (js)

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Can anyone explain why the last example prints `42` instead of `Promise { ... }`?

```
let f = async function () { return 42; }
let g = async function () { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(42)); }

f()
-> Promise { ... }

await f()
-> 42

g()
-> Promise { ... }

await g()
-> 42
```

It seems like the promise created by `async` is somehow being merged with the promise created and returned inside `g()`?

Comment: `await` doesn't create a promise. Also, you shouldn't return a promise from a async function.

Comment: There is no such thing as a promise that resolves to a promise. They autoflatten. If you expect you'd need `await await f` that's never possible.

Comment: Promises are created automatically by `async`, not `await`. `await` is syntactic sugar for `.then()`

Comment: @tkausl You are correct about async/await and I have updated my post.

Comment: *"is somehow being merged with the promise"*: and that's one of the important features of promises. If a promise is resolved with a promise, the first promise is locked-in -- it will settle when the second promise settles, and with the same outcome. [EcmaScript2015 specs, 25.4 Promise Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects)